Virtual function with template
I have following piece of code:
class Foo
{
private:
    FooProperties;
};

class Bar
{
private:
    BarProperties m_prop;
};

class Baz
{
private:
    BazProperties
};

class Properties Handler
{
};

class FooRopertiesHandler : public PropertiesHandler
{
};

class BarPropertiesHandler : public PropertiesHandler
{
};

class BazPropertiesHandler : 
public PropertiesHandler
{
};

All 3 classes of Foo, Bar and Baz are not connected to each other and may or may not share some of the properties.
What I'd like to do is to have a virtual template function SetObject() in a base class PropertiesHandler and then all three handlers will have specific implementation setters based on the object. And then regular virtual function ApplyProperties() which will apply all properties to a specific object passed to it.
However I can't have template virtual in C++. What would be the alternative?
Maybe I can have just a template function setter and then virtual ApplyProperties()? Will this work?

What is an alternative to using templates on a virtual member function? and Alternative for virtual template functions

You could also use a templated base class like this: https://godbolt.org/z/1r3vWxrPo

@RoQuOTriX, templated base class for Foo, Bar and Baz?Or for the handlers? How? Can you make some code example?

In general I would not mix static and dynamic polymorphism. Have a look at CRTP, where you inherit directly from an implementation of an abstract baseclass (also know as CRTP/mixin)

@user12002570 will look closer and come back to you. But from a quick look at first answer - it doesn't really fit. I need pure C++ implementation that will work on C++11 compiler.

@Igor have a look at the godbolt link, not able to post an answer anymore. The Handlers can be templated. Not sure about your requirements in detail

@Igor you probably think from wrong side, "how I write magical virtual functions". You should write the usage side first. If it is actually static polymorphism then use that, if it is anyway selection from variants then use that and if it is just mundane non-template virtual call then use that.

@RoQuOTriX, just did. Applying properties is not just a simple assignment - I need to perform different talk on the objects as well. That why t is called Handler classes not just simple Properties one. And that the reason I want ApplyProperties to be virtual, so every implementation can have its own apply function.

You are thinking about something like this https://godbolt.org/z/3dzo9Thqv but you are wrong, the whole thing doesn't need polymorphism to begin with, fyi that was called double dispatch which is what i was hinting for in the other question.

@AhmedAEK, I looked at your code. Problem is you presume that there is some common properties available and I can create some Base class from Foo, Bar and Baz. There are none. So I can't make it work because there will be too much code repetition and maintaining it will be a nightmare. Also, why do I need to have 2 apply functions where one uses double casting. Looks very weird...

you can replace that using either a variant or std::any holding a std::reference_wrapper, for c++11 i am sure boost has implementations for those. https://godbolt.org/z/hba95K35E or you can just not use double dispatch and just go with static polymorphism all the way, double dispatch is useful when you want to go from two base types into two derived types in a type-safe way, and using CRTP greatly reduces the repeated code, you only need to implement one small function which has all the types resolved. (Apply_impl in this example).

@AhmedAEK, you are still checking the type in the PropertyHandlerCRTP. Why? The idea is to implement everything in the derived classes and have base only define the interface.

you can take the code inside PropertyHandlerCRTP and jam it into each and every property handler, it is just there to reduce the boilerplate, as for why you need to check the type, because the call site expects std::any which can (as its name implies) be any object, you need to check that the user didn't make a mistake, otherwise you can just pass in a void pointer and assume the type passed is always correct, ie: virtual void Apply(void*) ....

@AhmedAEK, std::any is C++17. don't want that. need C++11 compatible code. Using void * looks too C-like.

boost::any ... or you can write your own, it is like 100 lines.
